# Actionscript Netstream seek set start point

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video-capture

I'am trying to set the start point where NetStream should start, but the seek method is working wrong, looks like because the video isn't yet loaded its seeks the nearest possible frame, what should I do set an completeEvent handle, but I didn't found any to use with NetStream, also is there another way to set the start position of the video? right after it loads?

Answer (score 0):

A large (file size) video may take a while to completely load. Do you really want to wait that long before you can seek?  How about just editing the video to start where you want it to? Even if you're not a real video editor you can easily trim things using Quicktime Pro.